# Изменение jsf страницы из другой страницы

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsf

Хочу по нажатию на ссылку на одной странице, изменить элемент другой страницы(изменить тэг) и что-бы это было real time, подскажите как можно это сделать.(можно с использованием js и jQuery).Изменение не требует коннекта с сервером, чисто графическая часть.

Comment: а что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: @michael_best я спрашиваю как это сделать, потому что еще не опытный, первый раз столкнулся.

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен. Приведите более конкретные примеры того, что у Вас есть, и чего Вы пытаетесь достигнуть. В частности что Вы подразумеваете под двумя страницами? Две разные вкладки в браузере со страницами одного и того же сайта? Или что?